# Where can I find the XSDs of DOCX XML files?

Tags: xml, xsd, ms-office, openxml, open-packaging-convention

I've created a docx file, unzipped it. Now I have:

- _rels (folder)
- docProps (folder)
- word (folder)
- **[Content_Types].xml**

The content of [Content_Types].xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/document.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/settings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/webSettings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

Where can I find [Content_Types].xml's xsd schema file?

("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types" - is not a regular web page, nor contains something related to xsd...)

Comment: You might find this useful: it's what I use when I need to look something up in the schema (as opposed to understanding what it's about, which is when I use the ECMA docs): http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/ss.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Content_Types].xml** defines the MIME media types for the package parts in Open Packaging Conventions container-file technology that's a part of OOXML.

See the [Standard ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) site, **Part 2** of any edition, for the OPC XSDs, including the `opc-contentTypes.xsd` which you seek.  It starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  blockDefault="#all">

  <xs:element name="Types" type="CT_Types"/>
```

**Part 4** has references and XSDs for other parts of OOXML such as WordprocessingML, SpreadsheetML, PresentationML, DrawingML, Shared MLs and Custom XML Schema.