# is it possible to define xml schema for a word document to be created by POI lib?

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, apache-poi, openxml

I have to generate word documents from my application against a entity which will contain some information about that entity, for this i am using POI.  
   But while using POI i have to decide like where i have to create a paragraph, where i have make text bold\italic etc based on a configuration in entity object which i could easily handle in the code. 
   
 
      But is there any way so that i can just define all these style/alignments etc information in any XML/XSL or in any other type of config so i can get rid of styling in my java code ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your title question, see [Where can I find the XSDs of DOCX XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36428294/290085)

Regarding your body question,

> But is there any way so that i can just define all these
>   style/alignments etc information in any XML/XSL or in any other type
>   of config so i can get rid of styling in my java code ?

Yes, of course, and it would be a wise design decision to do so.  Since DOCX is OOXML (within OPC) your XSLT will be able to generate OOXML character level formatting via `w:rPr` settings such as `w:b`, `w:i`, etc.

The challenge you'll be facing, however, is that you'll be forgoing the convenience provided by the POI API.  You'll also have to reconstruct the OPC if you want to produce a proper DOCX file rather than just an importable OOXML file.  For small projects, the learning curve required to wield OOXML directly is likely to be too steep to merit a direct-to-OOXML approach.